# Find and add/replace kMDItemKeywords attribute OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, search

I'm trying to find files (images) tagged with a specific tag and add (possibly replace) it with a new one.

Right now I come up with:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin '/Volumes/HDD_MED_201304/Photos' 'sampleTag' | xargs -0 -I {} sips -X newTag"
```

But it doesn't work. I receive a "No such file or directory" from terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sips -X` is used to extract a tag from an ICC profile file, like `sips -X mmod /tmp/a /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/iMac-2838C3DD-A394-78C1-4A5E-57649BBC5643.icc`.

Try using `exiftool` instead:

```
exiftool -keywords+='some keyword' -keywords+='another keyword' file.jpg
```

See http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html for more examples.